# Android Open Source (AOSP) build failure on Mac OS X: ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: android, xcode, macos, makefile, android-source

So I'm attempting to build the AOSP master branch, following the [Instructions here](https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html) to the letter.  I'm using Mac OS X 10.11, XCode 7.0.1, XCode Command Line Tools 7.0.1.

Has anyone seen this before, or know how to resolve it?

```
macbook-pro:android_5.1.1 awt$ gcc -v 

Configured with:
--prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr 
--with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1 
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72) 
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0 
Thread model: posix

macbook-pro:android_5.1.1 awt$ clang -v 
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72) 
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0 
Thread model: posix

macbook-pro:android_5.1.1 awt$ which clang 
/usr/bin/clang macbook-pro:android_5.1.1 
awt$ clang -v 
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72) 
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0 
Thread model: posix

macbook-pro:android_5.1.1 awt$ make -v 
GNU Make 3.81 Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc. This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0

#### make completed successfully  ####

macbook-pro:android_5.1.1 awt$ . build/envsetup.sh  
including device/asus/deb/vendorsetup.sh 
including device/asus/flo/vendorsetup.sh 
including device/asus/fugu/vendorsetup.sh 
including device/asus/grouper/vendorsetup.sh 
including device/asus/tilapia/vendorsetup.sh 
including device/generic/mini-emulator-arm64/vendorsetup.sh 
including device/generic/mini-emulator-armv7-a-neon/vendorsetup.sh 
including device/generic/mini-emulator-mips/vendorsetup.sh 
including device/generic/mini-emulator-x86/vendorsetup.sh 
including device/generic/mini-emulator-x86_64/vendorsetup.sh 
including device/htc/flounder/vendorsetup.sh 
including device/lge/hammerhead/vendorsetup.sh 
including device/lge/mako/vendorsetup.sh 
including device/moto/shamu/vendorsetup.sh 
including device/samsung/manta/vendorsetup.sh 
including sdk/bash_completion/adb.bash 

macbook-pro:android_5.1.1 awt$ lunch

You're building on Darwin

Lunch menu... pick a combo:
     1. aosp_arm-eng
     2. aosp_arm64-eng
     3. aosp_mips-eng
     4. aosp_mips64-eng
     5. aosp_x86-eng
     6. aosp_x86_64-eng
     7. aosp_deb-userdebug
     8. aosp_flo-userdebug
     9. full_fugu-userdebug
     10. aosp_fugu-userdebug
     11. aosp_grouper-userdebug
     12. aosp_tilapia-userdebug
     13. mini_emulator_arm64-userdebug
     14. m_e_arm-userdebug
     15. mini_emulator_mips-userdebug
     16. mini_emulator_x86-userdebug
     17. mini_emulator_x86_64-userdebug
     18. aosp_flounder-userdebug
     19. aosp_hammerhead-userdebug
     20. aosp_mako-userdebug
     21. aosp_shamu-userdebug
     22. aosp_manta-userdebug

Which would you like? [aosp_arm-eng] 1

============================================ 
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL 
PLATFORM_VERSION=5.1.51 
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_arm 
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng 
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release 
TARGET_BUILD_APPS= 
TARGET_ARCH=arm 
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a 
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic 
TARGET_2ND_ARCH= 
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT= 
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT= 
HOST_ARCH=x86_64 
HOST_OS=darwin 
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Darwin-15.0.0-x86_64-i386-64bit 
HOST_CROSS_OS= 
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release 
BUILD_ID=AOSP 
OUT_DIR=out
============================================

macbook-pro:android_5.1.1 awt$ make -j8
============================================ 
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL   
PLATFORM_VERSION=5.1.51 
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_arm 
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng 
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release 
TARGET_BUILD_APPS= 
TARGET_ARCH=arm 
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a 
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic 
TARGET_2ND_ARCH= 
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT= 
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT= 
HOST_ARCH=x86_64 HOST_OS=darwin 
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Darwin-15.0.0-x86_64-i386-64bit 
HOST_CROSS_OS= 
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release 
BUILD_ID=AOSP 
OUT_DIR=out
============================================ 
prebuilts/clang/darwin-x86/host/3.6/bin/clang++ -m64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -Wl,-syslibroot,/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.8     -target x86_64-apple-darwin -std=c++11 -g -W -Wall -MMD -MP -O -DNOLOG -o out/host/darwin-x86/bin/ckati out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/command.o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/dep.o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/eval.o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/exec.o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/expr.o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/file.o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/file_cache.o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/fileutil.o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/find.o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/flags.o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/func.o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/io.o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/log.o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/main.o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/ninja.o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/parser.o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/rule.o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/stats.o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/stmt.o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/string_piece.o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/stringprintf.o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/strutil.o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/symtab.o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/timeutil.o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/var.o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/version.o  prebuilts/clang/darwin-x86/host/3.6/bin/clang++   -m64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk
-Wl,-syslibroot,/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.8     -target x86_64-apple-darwin -std=c++11 -Wall -Werror -MMD -MP -o out/host/darwin-x86/bin/makeparallel out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/makeparallel_intermediates/makeparallel.o Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "__ZNKSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE4findEcm", referenced from:
      __ZN12_GLOBAL__N_19ShellFuncERKNSt3__16vectorIP5ValueNS0_9allocatorIS3_EEEEP9EvaluatorPNS0_12basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS4_IcEEEE in func.o
      __Z11NoLineBreakRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE in strutil.o   "__ZNKSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE5rfindEcm", referenced from:
      __Z13NormalizePathPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE in strutil.o   "__ZNKSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE7compareEPKc", referenced from:
      __Z10NeedsRegenPKcS0_bbdRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEE in ninja.o
      __ZN14NinjaGenerator13GenerateNinjaERKNSt3__16vectorIP7DepNodeNS0_9allocatorIS3_EEEEbRKNS0_12basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS4_IcEEEE in ninja.o
      __ZN14NinjaGenerator13GenerateShellEv in ninja.o
      __ZN14NinjaGenerator8EmitNodeEP7DepNode in ninja.o   "__ZNKSt3__119__shared_weak_count13__get_deleterERKSt9type_info", referenced from:
      __ZTVNSt3__120__shared_ptr_emplaceI4RuleNS_9allocatorIS1_EEEE in dep.o
      __ZTVNSt3__120__shared_ptr_emplaceINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEENS4_IS6_EEEE in dep.o   "__ZNKSt3__120__vector_base_commonILb1EE20__throw_length_errorEv", referenced from:
      __ZNSt3__16vectorIP7CommandNS_9allocatorIS2_EEE21__push_back_slow_pathIRKS2_EEvOT_ in command.o
      __Z7MakeDepP9EvaluatorRKNSt3__16vectorINS1_10shared_ptrI4RuleEENS1_9allocatorIS5_EEEERKNS1_13unordered_mapI6SymbolP4VarsNS1_4hashISC_EENS1_8equal_toISC_EENS6_INS1_4pairIKSC_SE_EEEEEERKNS2_ISC_NS6_ISC_EEEEPNS2_IP7DepNodeNS6_ISV_EEEE in dep.o
      __ZN12_GLOBAL__N_18RuleTrie3AddE11StringPieceNSt3__110shared_ptrI4RuleEE in dep.o
      __ZN4RuleC2ERKS_ in dep.o
      __ZNSt3__16vectorI6SymbolNS_9allocatorIS1_EEE21__push_back_slow_pathIRKS1_EEvOT_ in dep.o
      __ZNSt3__16vectorI6SymbolNS_9allocatorIS1_EEE21__push_back_slow_pathIS1_EEvOT_ in dep.o
      __ZNSt3__16vectorINS_10shared_ptrI4RuleEENS_9allocatorIS3_EEE21__push_back_slow_pathIRKS3_EEvOT_ in dep.o
      ...   "__ZNSt3__112__next_primeEm", referenced from:
      __ZNSt3__112__hash_tableI11StringPieceNS_4hashIS1_EENS_8equal_toIS1_EENS_9allocatorIS1_EEE6rehashEm in command.o
      __ZNSt3__112__hash_tableINS_17__hash_value_typeI6SymbolP3VarEENS_22__unordered_map_hasherIS2_S5_NS_4hashIS2_EELb1EEENS_21__unordered_map_equalIS2_S5_NS_8equal_toIS2_EELb1EEENS_9allocatorIS5_EEE6rehashEm in command.o
      __ZN12_GLOBAL__N_18RuleTrie3AddE11StringPieceNSt3__110shared_ptrI4RuleEE in dep.o
      __ZNSt3__112__hash_tableINS_17__hash_value_typeI11StringPieceNS_6vectorINS_10shared_ptrI4RuleEENS_9allocatorIS6_EEEEEENS_22__unordered_map_hasherIS2_SA_NS_4hashIS2_EELb1EEENS_21__unordered_map_equalIS2_SA_NS_8equal_toIS2_EELb1EEENS7_ISA_EEE6rehashEm in dep.o
      __ZNSt3__112__hash_tableINS_17__hash_value_typeI6SymbolNS_10shared_ptrI4RuleEEEENS_22__unordered_map_hasherIS2_S6_NS_4hashIS2_EELb1EEENS_21__unordered_map_equalIS2_S6_NS_8equal_toIS2_EELb1EEENS_9allocatorIS6_EEE6rehashEm in dep.o
      __ZNSt3__112__hash_tableI6SymbolNS_4hashIS1_EENS_8equal_toIS1_EENS_9allocatorIS1_EEE6rehashEm in dep.o
      __ZNSt3__112__hash_tableINS_17__hash_value_typeI6SymbolP7DepNodeEENS_22__unordered_map_hasherIS2_S5_NS_4hashIS2_EELb1EEENS_21__unordered_map_equalIS2_S5_NS_8equal_toIS2_EELb1EEENS_9allocatorIS5_EEE6rehashEm in dep.o
      ...   "__ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE5eraseEmm", referenced from:
      __Z21GetDepfileFromCommandPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEES6_ in ninja.o   "__ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6__initEPKcm", referenced from:
      __ZN16CommandEvaluator4EvalEP7DepNodePNSt3__16vectorIP7CommandNS2_9allocatorIS5_EEEE in command.o
      __ZNK12_GLOBAL__N_17AutoVar11DebugStringEv in command.o
      __ZN9Evaluator10EvalAssignEPK10AssignStmt in eval.o
      __ZN12_GLOBAL__N_18Executor8ExecNodeEP7DepNodeS2_ in exec.o
      __ZNK5Value11DebugStringEv in expr.o
      __Z10JoinValuesRKNSt3__16vectorIP5ValueNS_9allocatorIS2_EEEEPKc in expr.o
      __ZNK6VarRef12DebugString_Ev in expr.o
      ...   "__ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6__initEPKcmm", referenced from:
      __Z21GetDepfileFromCommandPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEES6_ in ninja.o   "__ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6appendEPKc", referenced from:
      __ZNK12_GLOBAL__N_17AutoVar11DebugStringEv in command.o
      __Z10JoinValuesRKNSt3__16vectorIP5ValueNS_9allocatorIS2_EEEEPKc in expr.o
      __ZNK4Expr12DebugString_Ev in expr.o
      __ZN12_GLOBAL__N_116FindEmulatorImpl22ConstructDirectoryTreeERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEE in find.o
      __ZN12_GLOBAL__N_19WordsFuncERKNSt3__16vectorIP5ValueNS0_9allocatorIS3_EEEEP9EvaluatorPNS0_12basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS4_IcEEEE in func.o
      __ZN12_GLOBAL__N_112RealpathFuncERKNSt3__16vectorIP5ValueNS0_9allocatorIS3_EEEEP9EvaluatorPNS0_12basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS4_IcEEEE in func.o
      __ZN12_GLOBAL__N_19ShellFuncERKNSt3__16vectorIP5ValueNS0_9allocatorIS3_EEEEP9EvaluatorPNS0_12basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS4_IcEEEE in func.o
      ...   "__ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6appendEPKcm", referenced from:
      __ZNK12_GLOBAL__N_19AutoAtVar4EvalEP9EvaluatorPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS3_11char_traitsIcEENS3_9allocatorIcEEEE in command.o
      __ZNK12_GLOBAL__N_111AutoLessVar4EvalEP9EvaluatorPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS3_11char_traitsIcEENS3_9allocatorIcEEEE in command.o
      __ZNK4Expr12DebugString_Ev in expr.o
      __ZNK12_GLOBAL__N_113DirentDirNode7RunFindERK11FindCommandiPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS4_11char_traitsIcEENS4_9allocatorIcEEEESB_ in find.o
      __ZNK12_GLOBAL__N_117DirentSymlinkNode7RunFindERK11FindCommandiPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS4_11char_traitsIcEENS4_9allocatorIcEEEESB_ in find.o
      __ZNK12_GLOBAL__N_114DirentFileNode7RunFindERK11FindCommandiPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS4_11char_traitsIcEENS4_9allocatorIcEEEESB_ in find.o
      __ZN12_GLOBAL__N_19SubstFuncERKNSt3__16vectorIP5ValueNS0_9allocatorIS3_EEEEP9EvaluatorPNS0_12basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS4_IcEEEE in func.o
      ...   "__ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6assignEPKc", referenced from:
      __Z17GetExecutablePathPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE in fileutil.o
      __ZN14NinjaGeneratorC2EPKcS1_P9Evaluatord in ninja.o
      __Z7AbsPath11StringPiecePNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEE in strutil.o   "__ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6assignEPKcm", referenced from:
      __ZNK11StringPiece12CopyToStringEPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEE in string_piece.o   "__ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6insertEmPKcm", referenced from:
      __ZN14NinjaGenerator14GenShellScriptERKNSt3__16vectorIP7CommandNS0_9allocatorIS3_EEEEPNS0_12basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS4_IcEEEESE_ in ninja.o   "__ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6resizeEmc", referenced from:
      __ZN12_GLOBAL__N_116FindEmulatorImpl10HandleFindERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEERK11FindCommandPS7_ in find.o
      __ZNK12_GLOBAL__N_113DirentDirNode7RunFindERK11FindCommandiPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS4_11char_traitsIcEENS4_9allocatorIcEEEESB_ in find.o
      __Z10LoadStringP7__sFILEPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEE in io.o
      __ZN14NinjaGenerator14GenShellScriptERKNSt3__16vectorIP7CommandNS0_9allocatorIS3_EEEEPNS0_12basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS4_IcEEEESE_ in ninja.o
      __ZN14NinjaGenerator11EmitDepfileEPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEE in ninja.o
      __ZN14NinjaGenerator16TranslateCommandEPKcPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEE in ninja.o
      __Z12StringPrintfPKcz in stringprintf.o
      ...   "__ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE7reserveEm", referenced from:
      __ZN16CommandEvaluator4EvalEP7DepNodePNSt3__16vectorIP7CommandNS2_9allocatorIS5_EEEE in command.o
      __Z4ExecRKNSt3__16vectorIP7DepNodeNS_9allocatorIS2_EEEEP9Evaluator in exec.o
      __ZN11FindCommand5ParseERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEE in find.o
      __ZN12_GLOBAL__N_117FindCommandParser9ParseTestEv in find.o
      __ZN12_GLOBAL__N_116FindEmulatorImpl10HandleFindERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEERK11FindCommandPS7_ in find.o
      __ZN12_GLOBAL__N_110DirentNodeC2ERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEE in find.o
      __ZN12_GLOBAL__N_17AndFuncERKNSt3__16vectorIP5ValueNS0_9allocatorIS3_EEEEP9EvaluatorPNS0_12basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS4_IcEEEE in func.o
      ...   "__ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE9__grow_byEmmmmmm", referenced from:
      __ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6appendIPKcEENS_9enable_ifIXsr21__is_forward_iteratorIT_EE5valueERS5_E4typeESA_SA_ in expr.o
      __ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6appendIPcEENS_9enable_ifIXsr21__is_forward_iteratorIT_EE5valueERS5_E4typeES9_S9_ in fileutil.o
      __ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6appendIPKcEENS_9enable_ifIXsr21__is_forward_iteratorIT_EE5valueERS5_E4typeESA_SA_ in main.o
      __ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6appendIPKcEENS_9enable_ifIXsr21__is_forward_iteratorIT_EE5valueERS5_E4typeESA_SA_ in rule.o
      __ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6appendIPKcEENS_9enable_ifIXsr21__is_forward_iteratorIT_EE5valueERS5_E4typeESA_SA_ in strutil.o
      __ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6appendIPKcEENS_9enable_ifIXsr21__is_forward_iteratorIT_EE5valueERS5_E4typeESA_SA_ in symtab.o   "__ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE9push_backEc", referenced from:
      __ZN12_GLOBAL__N_1L13ReplaceSuffixE6SymbolS0_ in dep.o
      __ZN10DepBuilder9BuildPlanE6SymbolS0_ in dep.o
      __ZN12_GLOBAL__N_116FindEmulatorImpl22ConstructDirectoryTreeERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEE in find.o
      __ZNK12_GLOBAL__N_113DirentDirNode7RunFindERK11FindCommandiPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS4_11char_traitsIcEENS4_9allocatorIcEEEESB_ in find.o
      __ZNK12_GLOBAL__N_117DirentSymlinkNode7RunFindERK11FindCommandiPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS4_11char_traitsIcEENS4_9allocatorIcEEEESB_ in find.o
      __ZNK12_GLOBAL__N_114DirentFileNode7RunFindERK11FindCommandiPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS4_11char_traitsIcEENS4_9allocatorIcEEEESB_ in find.o
      __ZN12_GLOBAL__N_17DirFuncERKNSt3__16vectorIP5ValueNS0_9allocatorIS3_EEEEP9EvaluatorPNS0_12basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS4_IcEEEE in func.o
      ...   "__ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEC1ERKS5_", referenced from:
      __Z10JoinValuesRKNSt3__16vectorIP5ValueNS_9allocatorIS2_EEEEPKc in expr.o
      __ZN8MakefileC2ERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEE in file.o
      __ZN24MakefileCacheManagerImpl12ReadMakefileERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEE in file_cache.o
      __ZN24MakefileCacheManagerImplD2Ev in file_cache.o
      __ZNSt3__112__hash_tableINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEENS_4hashIS6_EENS_8equal_toIS6_EENS4_IS6_EEE15__insert_uniqueERKS6_ in file_cache.o
      __ZN11FindCommand5ParseERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEE in find.o
      __ZN12_GLOBAL__N_117FindCommandParser9ParseFactE11StringPiece in find.o
      ...   "__ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEC1ERKS5_mmRKS4_", referenced from:
      __Z11NoLineBreakRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE in strutil.o   "__ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEED1Ev", referenced from:
      __ZN16CommandEvaluator4EvalEP7DepNodePNSt3__16vectorIP7CommandNS2_9allocatorIS5_EEEE in command.o
      __ZN12_GLOBAL__N_17AutoVar9AppendVarEP9EvaluatorP5Value in command.o
      __ZNK12_GLOBAL__N_17AutoVar6StringEv in command.o
      __ZNK12_GLOBAL__N_17AutoVar11DebugStringEv in command.o
      __ZNK12_GLOBAL__N_114AutoSuffixDVar4EvalEP9EvaluatorPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS3_11char_traitsIcEENS3_9allocatorIcEEEE in command.o
      __ZNK12_GLOBAL__N_114AutoSuffixFVar4EvalEP9EvaluatorPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS3_11char_traitsIcEENS3_9allocatorIcEEEE in command.o
      __ZN12_GLOBAL__N_1L13ReplaceSuffixE6SymbolS0_ in dep.o
      ...   "__ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEaSERKS5_", referenced from:
      __ZN16CommandEvaluator4EvalEP7DepNodePNSt3__16vectorIP7CommandNS2_9allocatorIS5_EEEE in command.o
      __ZN12_GLOBAL__N_19ShellFuncERKNSt3__16vectorIP5ValueNS0_9allocatorIS3_EEEEP9EvaluatorPNS0_12basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS4_IcEEEE in func.o
      __ZN14NinjaGenerator25GetDescriptionFromCommandE11StringPiecePNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEE in ninja.o
      __ZN6Parser5ErrorERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEE in parser.o   "__ZNSt3__119__shared_weak_count12__add_sharedEv", referenced from:
      __ZN12_GLOBAL__N_18RuleTrie3AddE11StringPieceNSt3__110shared_ptrI4RuleEE in dep.o
      __ZNK12_GLOBAL__N_18RuleTrie3GetE11StringPiecePNSt3__16vectorINS2_10shared_ptrI4RuleEENS2_9allocatorIS6_EEEE in dep.o
      __ZN10DepBuilder13PopulateRulesERKNSt3__16vectorINS0_10shared_ptrI4RuleEENS0_9allocatorIS4_EEEE in dep.o
      __ZN10DepBuilder20PopulateImplicitRuleENSt3__110shared_ptrI4RuleEE in dep.o
      __ZN10DepBuilder20PopulateExplicitRuleENSt3__110shared_ptrI4RuleEE in dep.o
      __ZN10DepBuilder18PopulateSuffixRuleENSt3__110shared_ptrI4RuleEE6Symbol in dep.o
      __ZNSt3__16vectorINS_10shared_ptrI4RuleEENS_9allocatorIS3_EEE21__push_back_slow_pathIRKS3_EEvOT_ in dep.o
      ...   "__ZNSt3__119__shared_weak_count16__release_sharedEv", referenced from:
      __ZN12_GLOBAL__N_18RuleTrie3AddE11StringPieceNSt3__110shared_ptrI4RuleEE in dep.o
      __ZN12_GLOBAL__N_18RuleTrieD1Ev in dep.o
      __ZN10DepBuilder13PopulateRulesERKNSt3__16vectorINS0_10shared_ptrI4RuleEENS0_9allocatorIS4_EEEE in dep.o
      __ZN10DepBuilder20PopulateImplicitRuleENSt3__110shared_ptrI4RuleEE in dep.o
      __ZN10DepBuilder20PopulateExplicitRuleENSt3__110shared_ptrI4RuleEE in dep.o
      __ZN10DepBuilder18PopulateSuffixRuleENSt3__110shared_ptrI4RuleEE6Symbol in dep.o
      __ZNSt3__16vectorINS_10shared_ptrI4RuleEENS_9allocatorIS3_EEE21__push_back_slow_pathIRKS3_EEvOT_ in dep.o
      ...   "__ZNSt3__119__shared_weak_countD2Ev", referenced from:
      __ZNSt3__120__shared_ptr_emplaceI4RuleNS_9allocatorIS1_EEED1Ev in dep.o
      __ZNSt3__120__shared_ptr_emplaceI4RuleNS_9allocatorIS1_EEED0Ev in dep.o
      __ZNSt3__120__shared_ptr_emplaceINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEENS4_IS6_EEED1Ev in dep.o
      __ZNSt3__120__shared_ptr_emplaceINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEENS4_IS6_EEED0Ev in dep.o
      __ZNSt3__120__shared_ptr_pointerIP4RuleNS_14default_deleteIS1_EENS_9allocatorIS1_EEED1Ev in eval.o
      __ZNSt3__120__shared_ptr_pointerIP4RuleNS_14default_deleteIS1_EENS_9allocatorIS1_EEED0Ev in eval.o   "__ZTINSt3__119__shared_weak_countE", referenced from:
      __ZTINSt3__120__shared_ptr_emplaceI4RuleNS_9allocatorIS1_EEEE in dep.o
      __ZTINSt3__120__shared_ptr_emplaceINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEENS4_IS6_EEEE in dep.o
      __ZTINSt3__120__shared_ptr_pointerIP4RuleNS_14default_deleteIS1_EENS_9allocatorIS1_EEEE in eval.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) make: *** [out/host/darwin-x86/bin/ckati] Error 1 make:
*** Waiting for unfinished jobs.... Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "__ZNKSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE4findEcm", referenced from:
      _main in makeparallel.o   "__ZNKSt3__120__vector_base_commonILb1EE20__throw_length_errorEv", referenced from:
      _main in makeparallel.o
      __ZNSt3__16vectorINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEENS4_IS6_EEE21__push_back_slow_pathIS6_EEvOT_ in makeparallel.o
      __ZNSt3__16vectorIPcNS_9allocatorIS1_EEE21__push_back_slow_pathIS1_EEvOT_ in makeparallel.o   "__ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6__initEPKcm", referenced from:
      _main in makeparallel.o   "__ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6__initEPKcmm", referenced from:
      _main in makeparallel.o   "__ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6appendEPKcm", referenced from:
      _main in makeparallel.o   "__ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6insertEmPKc", referenced from:
      _main in makeparallel.o   "__ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE7reserveEm", referenced from:
      _main in makeparallel.o   "__ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEC1ERKS5_mmRKS4_", referenced from:
      _main in makeparallel.o   "__ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEED1Ev", referenced from:
      _main in makeparallel.o
      __ZNSt3__16vectorINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEENS4_IS6_EEE21__push_back_slow_pathIS6_EEvOT_ in makeparallel.o   "__ZNSt3__19to_stringEi", referenced from:
      _main in makeparallel.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) make: *** [out/host/darwin-x86/bin/makeparallel] Error 1

#### make failed to build some targets (1 seconds) ####
```

Google groups thread [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-building/BQHmUOmLq4I), no luck on that front yet.

Comment: No solution to this yet.  I got it to build on a different Mac running 10.10 Yosemite and XCode 6.1.x.  Haven't found a solution for building on El Capitan with XCode 7.

Comment: stuck on the same error...

Comment: Any luck on this after the new upgrade?

Comment: I also add problems for building AOSP with same configuration as you but I did not have exactly the same issue. This post helped me a lot https://github.com/sjitech/build-android-in-OS-X-Yosemite-Xcode-7

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue, fixed by compiling it with 10.9 sdk
run following command before make to set sdk to 10.9

```
export MAC_SDK_VERSION="10.9"
```